Question on the method of characteristics for linear PDE (Courant-Hilbert)
Given a linear PDE such as
$$au_x+bu_y = c \tag{1}$$
with characteristic curves:
$$\frac{dx}{ds}=a, \frac{dy}{ds}=b, \frac{du}{ds}=c \tag{2'}$$
The characteristic curves through each point of a generic curve $C$($x(t), y(t), u(t)$) are the family of curves $x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t), u=u(s,t)$ that generate a surface $u(x,y)$ (solution of the PDE) if $s$ and $t$ can be expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$. A sufficient condition for this is the non vanishing of the Jacobian
$\Delta= x_sy_t-y_sx_t=ay_t-bx_t$
In the closing paragraph of 1.3.2 (examples) from chapter II of "Methods of mathematical physics" (Courant-Hilbert, vol II), I read

in case of a linear differential equation (1), where the functions $a,b,c$ do not depend explicitly on $u$, the vanishing of $\Delta$ along a noncharacteristic initial curve means, as we shall see, that the manifold determined by the system $x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t),u=u(s,t)$ is a cylindrical surface perpendicular to the $x,y$-plane. If we assume that $y_s u_t-u_s y_t \neq 0$ on $C$, then $x$ can be expressed as a function of $y$ and $u$. We show that $x=f(y,u)$ is independent of $u$. First, we note that, for linear differential equations, the relation $$\Delta_s = (a_x + b_y)\Delta $$ follows from (2') for the determinant $\Delta$, so that $\Delta$ vanishes everywhere provided it vanishes on $C$[...]

I have the following question:
Why $\Delta_s = (a_x + b_y)\Delta $ and why does this guaranteee that $\Delta$ vanishes everywhere provided it vanishes on $C$?

further edited the question to address the close votes.

$\triangle_s=(a_x+b_y)\triangle$ can be obtained by using the chain rule:
$$\triangle_s=(a_xx_s+a_yy_s)y_t+ay_{ts}-(b_xx_s+b_yy_s)x_t-bx_{ts}$$
Now we assume $y_{ts}=y_{st}$ and $x_{ts}=x_{st}$ thus
$$\triangle_s=(a_xx_s+a_yy_s)y_t+ab_t-(b_xx_s+b_yy_s)x_t-ba_t$$
Now use again the chain rule for $a_t,b_t$ and conclude your result.
$\triangle_s=(a_x+b_y)\triangle$ is an equation we can solve:
$$\triangle(s,t)=D(t)e^{\int_0^sa_x(x(\sigma,t),y(\sigma,t))+b_y(x(\sigma,t),y(\sigma,t))\mathbb{d}\sigma}
$$
thus if we know $\triangle$ vanishes on $C$ meaning $\triangle(t,0)=0\ \forall t$ we may conclude $D\equiv 0$ and therefore $\triangle\equiv0$.
